# links in iframe aren't opening wysiwyg editor

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe that I use as wysiwyg text editor. One of the option is to post a link. The problem is that my link don't open anything the `cursor:pointer` style isn't even there. I have to right click on them and click on open in a new tab for them to do something. I'd like them to open in a new window so when the user is entering his text with his links he can click on those. I tried `target="_blank"` `_new` and `_parent`. These are not working.

My code looks like this:

```
<input value="send" type="button" onclick="iLink(); "/>
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField"/>
```

Basically when the send button is pressed a link (user input) is rendered in the body of the iframe. The link will looks like this :

The link is given by user input, I hardcoded the link here to have minimum code!

```
<a target="_top" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441253/links-in-iframe-arent-opening/32441350#32441350" style="cursor:pointer">link</a>
```

I previously put `href="alink.com"` here that's why all the comments below are mentioning my link isn't valid.

So basically my output is like this:

```
<div class="iframeEditorContainer" style="height: 30em; margin: auto;">
    <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField">
       #document
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
             <a target="_blank" href="http://www.pianoscales.org/major.html" style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:#50bfff; cursor:pointer"> pîano scales </a>
          </body>
        </html> 
   </iframe>    
</div>
```

I didn't call "alink.com", I hardcoded it for the sake of readability. Links that I call are from user input and are opening on right click -> open tab. I changed it to a link to this post so there is no confusion.

Comment: `alink.com` is not a valid URL unless you have a file called `alink.com` on your server. It either needs the protocol prefix (e.g. `http://`) or a protocol relative prefix (e.g. `//`)

Comment: I didn't call alink it's just for SO. It's any input from user but I didn't want to put the js code in this thread.

Comment: If you aren't willing to add the actual output it's basically impossible to help you.

Comment: @PeeHaa alink to be replaced by any user submitted link. Anyway I think I won't use iframe and just an editable div.

Comment: At least try to isolate and minimize the actual problem code. As it currently stands there is no way to know what is going on.

Comment: Care to provide more code? Like the `iLink();` function.

Comment: @PeeHaa Do you mean that the problem is not in the code I provided but elsewhere ? I changed the link with a real output I have.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada Done. it's just outputting the output I specified originally.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada I rejected your edit because my post originally didn't contain any js. You asked for it. This post isn't about javascript and I would like if possible not having javascript answers like opening a new page on a onclick event. As I will have to clean all that for xss.

Comment: @Ced I don't think that detail is enough to get answer. I'm sorry, I couldn't be helpful here.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada No problemo thanks for trying though. I appreciate it. I doubt the javascript is the issue though because it's just a black box that outputs an anchor tag. Cheers have a nice day.